# Is victoriametrics read api asynchronous?

Tags: victoriametrics

Is victoriametrics read api asynchronous? If i have 5 microservices that read from it will each read request be executed in parallel?

Comment: Yes, VictoriaMetrics API is async so the queries will run in parallel.

Comment: Ok, so assume one has many rules in vmalert that are enforced on victoriametrics. I assume that it will have high iteration duration for rule enforcement. In this case, what is the solution for scaling up and reducing the iteration duration?

Comment: would it be running multiple vmalert instances for rule enforcement or scaling up victoriametrics?

Comment: vmalert runs configured rule groups concurrently. But rules within the group are executed sequentially, unless `concurrency ` param is changed - see https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmalert.html#groups


To scale VM's capabilities to handle many parallel requests one should consider scaling vmselect components horizontally - see https://docs.victoriametrics.com/Cluster-VictoriaMetrics.html#architecture-overview


Adding more vmselects is preferred for serving many lightweight parallel requests. Scaling vmselect vertically (by adding CPUs) is preferred to speed up requests execution.